# Mongoose | NodeJS : How to assing two 'ref' to same model term and populate it?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

UPDATED:
I tried this:

```
  ad:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ad' }],
  car:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]
```

It works, but I can't order by, so, still stucked..

```
.populate('ad')
.populate('car')
.sort({createdAt:-1})
```

(I would like to order by createdAt or updatedAt time)

That's what I tried before the following:

I am really stuck, and I know too that I just need I little help to solve it.

I am working nodeJS and HBS project (web site as craigslist).

I have different models, for different kinks of category:
jobs has its own view
cars has its own view
and so on...

I have a user model, that contains every ad they posted.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true,
    lowercase:true,
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid']
  },
  password:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    trim:true
  },
  ad:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'},{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Car'}]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at"
  }
});
```

As you can see, I have this:

```
ad:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'},{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Car'}]
```

In my mongoose database, I can save this data through a $push:

```
.then(ad => {
            User.updateOne({email:ad.email},{$push:{ad:ad._id}})
            .then(() => res.render('ads/test'))
          })
```

Everything works, mongodb:

```
//mongodb database
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1e28663128e9643c523712"),
    "ad" : [
        ObjectId("5e1e28633128e9643c523711"),
        ObjectId("5e1e28733128e9643c523713")
    ],
    "email" : "whatever@whatever.com",
    "password" : "$whatever$whatever.whatever",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-01-14T20:45:26.262Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-01-14T20:45:39.694Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So, I have my two ads from different models (model A: Job Category Posting, model B: Car category posting) and their ids:

```
"ad" : [
            ObjectId("5e1e28633128e9643c523711"),
            ObjectId("5e1e28733128e9643c523713")
        ]
```

After that, in my user controller, I try to populate... but I just do it in one model:

```
module.exports.myAds = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({email:req.session.currentUser.email})
    .populate({path: 'ad', options: { sort: { 'updated_at': -1 }}})
    .then(ads => {
      console.log(ads)
      res.render('users/my-ads', { ads:ads } )
    })
    .catch(err => next(err))
}
```

Please, I need to solve this. What am I doing wrong?

I looked for same explanations, but no one fits me.

I tried too, to split `ad` in:

```
 ad:[{test_1:{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Ad'}},{test_2:{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Car'}}]
```

But not even a good result.
Maybe I am wrong in $push to test_1 / test_2 or even when I populate?

Comment: have you tried to put the 2 ids in a single array so it is stored as an array of arrays that have 2 ids `ad:[[test_1:{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Ad'},test_2:{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Car'}]]`

Comment: How can I $push this from:
.then(ad => {
            User.updateOne({email:ad.email},{$push:{ad:ad._id}})
            .then(() => res.render('ads/test'))
          })
I mean, how to insert correctly in each array¿?

Comment: you can `{$push:{ad.$.test1: {ad.id}, ad.$.test2:{car.id}}` I think

Comment: but the nested array has to be different schema i saw now

Comment: that's what I did. Now, I handle after populate(), and create a new array with ad and car data, after that I will sort by updatedAt element.

Answer (score 1):

Populate is not ideal to user in this situation.
You should try to use aggregation with $lookup operator
see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
You will have more control over data this way

Comment: I don't understand how can I join or aggregate from different models to same one with this. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Aggregation is a pipeline that means for each consecutive operator the input comes from the output of previous operator's result. So, in the pipeline you can have any number of lookups serial wise. Just study about aggregation first it is really simple  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved doing this:

```
//ads.controller 
   // here I $push both kinds of ads (both models, ad and car) to user model


    User.findOne({email:email})
          .then(user => {
            if(user !== null){
              console.log(`User ${user.email} already exists`)
              newCarAd.save()
              .then(ad => {
                User.updateOne({email:ad.email},{$push:{car:ad._id}})
                .then(() => res.render('ads/test'))
              })
              .catch(error => {
                if (error instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
                  renderWithErrors(error.errors)
                } else {
                  next(error)
                }
              })

// user model

    const userSchema = new Schema({
    ...

      ad:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ad' }],
      car:[{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]
    }, {
      timestamps: {
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at"
      }
    });

//user controller 
//to populate and handle object from both models -pushed from 
//ads.controller-
    module.exports.myAds = (req, res, next) => {
      User.findOne({email:req.session.currentUser.email})
        .populate('ad')
        .populate('car')
        .sort({createdAt:-1})
        .then(ads => {
          //join all ads in same object to my-ads views
          const arrayUserAds = [...ads.ad,...ads.car];
  const allUserAds = arrayUserAds.sort((a,b) => {return b.updated_at -a.updated_at})

          res.render('users/my-ads', { ads:allUserAds } )
        })
        .catch(err => next(err))
    }
```